# no rule to make target but file exists, compiling

Tags: makefile, gfortran

I can't seem to debug this, could someone please help? The *.f90 file does exists and the directory is correct. I am not sure what it could be, the gfortran compiler works fine outside of the makefile.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/build/bin'
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/src/utils/allometry.f90', needed by 'allometry.o'.  Stop.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/build/bin'
    Makefile:24: recipe for target 'all' failed


This is the makefile

#----- Define path and compilation --------------------------------------------------------#
include paths.mk
include include.mk.$(OPT)
#----- Compiler commands. -----------------------------------------------------------------#
INCLUDES    = $(PAR_INCS) -I$(ED_INCS) $(HDF5_INCS) $(MPI_INCS) 
F90_COMMAND = $(F_COMP) -c $(F_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
FPP_COMMAND = $(F_COMP) -c -DUSE_INTERF=$(USE_INTERF) -DUSENC=$(USENC) -D$(CMACH)          \
              -DUSE_HDF5=$(USE_HDF5) -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=$(USE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO)          \
              -DUSE_MPIWTIME=$(USE_MPIWTIME) $(F_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
CXX_COMMAND = $(C_COMP) -c $(C_OPTS) -D$(CMACH) $(HDF5_INCS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
#----- Define archive and executable names. -----------------------------------------------#
EXE=$(BASE)/ed_$(ED_VERSION)-$(OPT)
LIBMODEL=$(BASE)/ed_$(ED_VERSION)-$(OPT).a

include objects.mk
#----- Define targets. --------------------------------------------------------------------#

all:
    make gendep
    #$(info $$EXE is [${EXE}])
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)

gendep:
    @echo ""
    ./generate_deps.sh $(ED_ROOT)
    @echo === Finished dependencies ===

$(EXE): $(LIBMODEL) $(MAINOBJ) 
    @echo ""
    $(LOADER) -o $(EXE) edmain.o $(LOADER_OPTS) $(LIBMODEL) $(HDF5_LIBS) $(PAR_LIBS)   \
    $(NC_LIBS) $(LIBS) $(LOADER_OPTS)
    @echo ""
    @echo Finished building === $(EXE)
    @echo ""

$(MAINOBJ):  $(MAIN) 
    @echo ""
    cp -f $< $(<F:.f90=.f90)
    $(F90_COMMAND) $(<F:.f90=.f90)
    rm -f $(<F:.f90=.f90) 

$(LIBMODEL): $(OBJ_MODEL)
    $(ARCHIVE) $(LIBMODEL) $(OBJ_MODEL)

FORCE: 

install:
    @echo ""
    ln -fs `pwd`/$(EXE) ../run/$(BASE)
    ln -fs `pwd`/$(EXE) ../test/$(BASE)
    @echo ""

clean:
    @echo ""
    rm -f $(LIBMODEL) $(EXE) *.o *.mod *.F90 *.f90 *.stb *.d dependency.mk 
    rm -f ../$(EXE) ../$(LIBMODEL)
    touch dependency.mk
    @echo ""

#----- Define rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------#
include rules.mk
```

Comment: For starters, replace the `make` invocations by just making `gendep` and `$(EXE)` dependencies of `all`.

Answer (score 1):

This makefile is a hot mess.  Why do you have the same command `make $(EXE)` listed 5 times in a row in the `all` recipe?  Why are you using `$(<F:.f90=.f90)` which just replaces the string `.f90` with an identical string `.f90`, essentially a no-op?

Further, we don't have enough information here to answer your question: you haven't provided the definition of the variables `MAINOBJ` or `OBJ_MODEL`, or more importantly, `MAIN`.  At least one of those is wrong.  Unless you've mis-transcribed the error message (please always cut and paste actual errors, don't try to manually type them in!!), then this:

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/src/utils/allometry.f90', needed by 'allometry.o'.  Stop.
```

tells you what the problem is; note there is no slash (`/`) at the beginning of this pathname, before `media`.  So this is not an absolute path, it's a relative path.  That means make is actually trying to find the file named `/media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/build/bin/media/f/fv/ED-2.1/ED/src/utils/allometry.f90` which clearly won't exist.

We can't tell you why this is happening because you haven't provided the information about how these variables are set.  Most likely the bad one is `MAIN` but it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, unfortunately this is someone's code so that's why it's so hard to navigate. I will look into what you mentioned and provide more info or open a new question. Thanks